# Put the flag secure and httponly in the cookies, in Liferay 6.2 (Localhost)

Tags: java, security, cookies, httponly, liferay-6.2

I want to apply the "secure" and "httponly" flags in the following names:

```
COOKIE_SUPPORT
GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID
JSESSIONID
LRF_SESSION_STATE (secure only)
ADRUM
```

Inside the web.xml file the following code has been added.
[cookie-config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3f2l.jpg)

The code shown in the image above only applies "secure" and "httponly" to JSESSIONID, but they do not affect other cookie names mentioned above.
[cookies image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJTrh.jpg)

How could I apply the "secure" flag to the following cookie names, in Liferay 6.2?

```
COOKIE_SUPPORT
GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID
LRF_SESSION_STATE (secure only)
ADRUM
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I was applying secure cookies on localhost, for this I had to configure the https protocol following the steps on the following web page ([configure-ssl-https-support-apache-tomcat-7-server](https://www.srccodes.com/configure-ssl-https-support-apache-tomcat-7-server/)), in addition to the code fragment of the "web.xml" file exposed in my main comment.

It helped me to test on localhost.

Regards.